# How can I access my Redux store after navigating to a new route using React Router?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm new to using React, React Router v4 and Redux. I can't seem to access my Redux store when using the `connect()` function in a route component. `this.props` logs the following to the console which I believe is the history object:

```
{match: {…}, location: {…}, history: {…}, staticContext: undefined, myJson: {…}, …}
```

However I can access my store on my index page only. It's just when I navigate to another page (e.g. /chat), my store becomes inaccessible. Please find my code below:

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">

          <Navigation />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path='/' component={Identity} />
            <Route path='/chat' component={Message} />
            <Route render={function() {
              return <p>Not found</p>
            }} />
          </Switch>

        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

**Message.js**

```
class Message extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Chat Screen</h1>
        <Inbox />
        <hr />
        <h2>Message</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    myJson: state.myJson
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Message));
```

**Index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <MuiThemeProvider>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </ Provider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

**Store.JS**

```
export default createStore(
  combineReducers({
    myJson
  }),
  {},
  applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, createLogger())
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: its loggin ```myJson: {…}``` too. check

Comment: Oh my word! Haha thank you @lavish for the letting me know. I haven't seen a log in that format before. You're right it is there. Thank you very much for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this issue, it was pointed out by @lavish that my Redux store was in fact accessible the whole time. The object was just being displayed differently when accessing a new route.